# OpenLayers XYZ example with map proxy script

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers

I always wondered if it would be possible to load a map from a public source with a script and display it using OpenLayers. It would also allow to create a map tile cache to allow faster load times.
So my question is how to load maps in OpenLayers using a XYZ source from a script hosted locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my quick solution for that:

First, I have created a proxy script to load the files for me:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/png'); 

$x = $_GET['x'];
$y = $_GET['y'];
$z = $_GET['z'];

$urlBegin = 'https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org';
$urlEnd = '.png';

$fullUrl = "$urlBegin/$z/$x/$y$urlEnd";


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $fullUrl,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36'
]);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $content

?>
```

After that, I have a simple example that loads the maps provided by this proxy script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>XYZ Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script>

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: 'fetch_map.php?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}'
            })
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 5
    })
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is pretty useful if you have trouble loading tiles from an external source, within the browser.